# Streaming Sink to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying create an s3 sink for my streaming output.  I figured a `BucketingSink` would be fine, since it is used for HDFS.  But it seems that an S3 url is not recognized as hdfs. I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while creating FileSystem when initializing the state of the BucketingSink.
Caused by: org.apache.flink.core.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemSchemeException: Cannot support file system for 's3' via Hadoop, because Hadoop is not in the classpath, or some classes are missing from the classpath.
```

Is there a way to make S3 work for `BucketingSink`, or is there another option other than `BucketingSink` that I can use?  I am currently running 1.5.2.  Would be happy to provide any additional information.

Thank you!

Edit:

My sink creation/using looks like the following:

```
val s3Sink = new BucketingSink[String]("s3://s3bucket/sessions")
s3Sink.setBucketer(new DateTimeBucketer[String]("yyyy-MM-dd--HHmm"))
s3Sink.setWriter(new StringWriter[String]())
s3Sink.setBatchSize(200)
s3Sink.setPendingPrefix("sessions-")
s3Sink.setPendingSuffix(".csv")

// Create stream and do stuff here 
stream.addSink(s3Sink)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have to include `hadoop-aws` jar to your Flink job. Refer to this link will help: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/ops/deployment/aws.html#provide-s3-filesystem-dependency

Comment: Isn't this only for if you are running on a hadoop cluster?  I am running on a local cluster.  Is it not possible to write to S3 from a local cluster?  I am including hadoop-aws(2.7.3), but still doesn't seem to work locally.  Including code that I am using in OP.

Comment: @Eumcoz `BucketingSink` relies on `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem` and related HDFS API to access S3, even you run the flink job locally.